# Shutdown from C program

Tags: c, shutdown

I'd love to do a proper shutdown of the Pi from a program (written in C) so that the only thing left to do is pull the power plug. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes.  What have you tried?

Comment: your question is about linux, not about RPi

Comment: I didn't even know where to start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call system():

```
#include <stdlib.h>
  ...
  system("sudo shutdown now");
```